# Prueba pico Jmeter

Tags: rendimiento, jmeter

Tengo una web que estoy probando su rendimiento, ya tengo la combinación entre usuarios y tiempso que me da el punto de quiebre (35000 usuarios en 1800 segundos)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso la prueba se detiene cuando colapsa por que eso es lo que quería, conocer el punto de quiebre.

Mi duda está en ¿Cómo configurar la prueba para tener en el reporte el tiempo en que la web tarda en restaurarse desde que se cae, yo lo coloco en "continue" pero al final en el reporte, no se como ver el tiempo de recuperación?
Gracias